# SQL grouping. How to select row with the highest column value when joined. No CTEs please

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I've been banging my head against the wall for something that I think should be simple but just cant get to work.

I'm trying to retrieve the row with the highest multi_flag value when I join table A and table B but I can't seem to get the SQL right  because it returns **all** the rows rather than the **one with the highest** multi_flag value.

Here are my tables...

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

This is almost my desired result but **only** if I leave out the `value_id` row

```
SELECT CATALOG, VENDOR_CODE, INVLINK, NAME_ID, MAX(multi_flag) AS multiflag 
FROM TBLINVENT_ATTRIBUTE AS A
INNER JOIN TBLATTRIBUTE_VALUE AS B 
ON A.VALUE_ID = B.VALUE_ID
GROUP BY CATALOG, VENDOR_CODE, INVLINK, NAME_ID
ORDER BY CATALOG DESC
```

[image]

This is close to what I want to retreive but not quite notice how it returns unique `name_id` and the highest `multi_flag` but I also need the `value_id` that belongs to such `multi_flag` / `name_id` grouping...

If I include the value_id in my SQL statement then it returns all rows and is no longer grouped

Notic ein the results below how it no longer returns the row for the highest `multi_flag` and how all the different values for `name_id` (Ex. `name_id` 1) are also returned

[image]

Comment: which database you are using ? .. removed the unused flag

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Why don't you want to use a CTE? Do you need to run this on MySQL as well?

Comment: I would create a view with id, max(multiflag).  Then join to it.  This is easily indexed (id, multiflag desc ) and you'd get the results you want.  Done.

Comment: For the results shown, I would report that as a defect to the service provider; there are no rows in the given table with the value VENDOR_CODE='SGP'. Or perhaps, the givens were incorrect [not truly representative], and a script [in text, not images] that gives the DDL and the sample data to INSERT would enable a reader to easily perform an actual test of their suggested query instead of providing untested queries that either can not run as coded or do not produce the desired output. Also of value is expected output from a query against the given input [text or images]; text if unordered

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use a sub-query, derived table or CTE to solve this problem. Performance will be depending on the amount of data you are querying.  To achieve your goal of getting the max multiflag you must first get the max value based on the grouping you want to achieve this you can use a CTE or sub query. The below CTE will give the max multi_flag  by value  that you can use to get the max multi_flag and then you can use that to join back to your other tables. I have three joins in this example but this can be reduce and as far a performance it may be better to use a subquery but you want know until you get the se the actual execution plans side by side.

;with highest_multi_flag as 
 (
  select value_id,  max(multi_flag) AS multiflag 
  FROM TBLINVENT_ATTRIBUTE 
  group by  value_id
 )
  select A.CATALOG, a.VENDOR_CODE, a.INVLINK, b.NAME_ID,m.multiflag
 from highest_multi_flag m 
 inner join TBLINVENT_ATTRIBUTE AS A  on a.VALUE_ID =b. m.VALUE_ID
INNER JOIN TBLATTRIBUTE_VALUE AS B   ON m.VALUE_ID = B.VALUE

Comment: Thanks for your response i will certainly try this although I don't know  CTE very well any oth suggestions? @tywan

Comment: @rojobo -- the CTE is already part of Tywan's solution; there isn't much to "know" beyold what he described.  It is invoked with the `with` clause.  In the absence of analytic / windowing functions, I think this is pretty much the best way to achieve what you seek

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way of doing this thanks for trying to help however. I am looking for a more conventional, simpler way of solving this CTE's are unecessary IMO

Comment: @rojobo: a CTE **is** a "conventional" way of solving SQL problems. Why do you think there is a simpler way? In this case you can convert the CTE to a derived table, but that doesn't change that actual solution.

Comment: Several reasons 
1. I have been working with SQL queries for 3 years now and this is the first time I've been advised to use CTEs... a quick search on CTE's say that most cases same results can be achieved using subqueries and CTEs are slow
2.My Databse Editor returns nothing when I run the CTE it just says is successful but I see nothing
3. No one else has used CTEs here so I dont want to introduce this if no one else has needed them in decades @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @rojobo: you should really learn about [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) don't stay in the 90s when it comes to SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm trying, and I will keep reading about this new to me concept, however I can see how CTEs can be part of an organization where they use strictly SQL as their main programming language (Ex. Universities) but not for what I.m trying to do.

Comment: @TywanTerrell Yes Im actually kind of wrapping it up actually your answer gave me that idea so as soon as i finished I will post the results and give you the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lateral too, its an other solution

```
  SELECT 
  A.CATALOG, A.VENDOR_CODE, A.INVLINK, B.NAME_ID, M.maxmultiflag 
  FROM TBLINVENT_ATTRIBUTE AS A
  inner join lateral
  (
   select max(B.multi_flag) as maxmultiflag from TBLINVENT_ATTRIBUTE C
   where A.VALUE_ID = C.VALUE_ID
  ) M on 1=1
  INNER JOIN TBLATTRIBUTE_VALUE AS B ON M.maxmultiflag = B.VALUE
```